# Countdown timer in Socket IO that is same for all clients

Tags: android, node.js, express, socket.io

I basically want a countdown timer of 70 seconds that resets back to 70, sort of an infinte countdown timer. A new game starts as the timer restarts.
Only problem is that if i put the counter in IO.on(connection), a new timer starts when a new player connects and then timer jumbles as it needs to show the exact same timer on all clients(android app). i tried putting the set interval above the io.on but it doesnt updates every second gives only one single value

below is my server code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var players = [];
var wingames ;
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'vaibhav_spinner',
    database: 'spinapi',

})
var newGameid = 1;
db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err)
})
server.listen(11694, function(){
    console.log("Server is now running...");
});
  var countdown = 70;


///
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Player Connected!");
if(players.length==1){
  var countdown = 70;

var countdowner =    setInterval(function() {
    countdown--;
  io.sockets.emit('timer', { countdown: countdown });
  socket.emit('lastwins',wingames);
  console.log(countdown);
if (countdown==0) {
  console.log("starting game");
  countdown = 70;
  newGameid ++;
  console.log(newGameid);


}


}, 1000);

}

    socket.emit('getPlayers', players);
  socket.emit('newgameid',{newgame: newGameid});
    socket.broadcast.emit('newPlayer', { id: socket.id });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("Player Disconnected");
        socket.broadcast.emit('playerDisconnected', { id: socket.id });
        for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
            if(players[i].id == socket.id){
                players.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    });



  socket.on('getcoins',function(data){
    var email = data.uname;
  console.log(" userEamil "+email);

   db.query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE uemail =  ?",[email] ,function (err, result, fields) {
     if(err) throw err;

     console.log(result);
    var ecoin = result[0].uCoins;
   console.log(" userCoins "+ecoin)
   io.emit('ucoins', ecoin);
  }); });




  socket.on('updatecoins',function(data){
    console.log("data= "+data.toString());
    var email = data.uname;
    var ucoins = data.ucoins;
  console.log(" userEmail "+email,"ucoins"+ucoins);

   db.query("UPDATE userinfo set uCoins = ? WHERE uemail = ?",[ucoins,email],function (err, result, fields) {
     if(err) throw err;

     console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
   });

 });

 // socket.on('getwinner',winnerbet(){
 //
 // });



    players.push(new player(socket.id, 0, 0));

});

function player(id, x, y){
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

i tried the way by putting that if the players.length==1 then the timer should start and not for all connections. but still couldnt get it correct. My android side code fetches correctly so i have no issues wi
th that

Comment: You have forgotten to remove the password. Now you have to change it!

Comment: removed the password, but i dont think it should matter anyhow without the actual ip of the server